# Getting single document position in MongoDB aggregate

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am having troubles with what seems to be a simple problem in MongoDB but I haven't had much luck searching online.

I have a collection that looks like this:

```
{ "id" : 'a18qv5k', "name" : "Joe", "myArray" : ['foo']}
{ "id" : 'cbuesvhg', "name" : "Adam", "myArray" : ['foo', 'bar', 'sample text']}
{ "id" : 'h106pw97', "name" : "Bill", "myArray" : ['bar', 'lorem ipsum']}
```

I want to run an aggregation query to return the entire collection, sorted by the number of elements contained in myArray. I've already found a way to do that:

```
const aggregation = [{
    $project: {
        id: 0,
        name: 1,
        dim: {
            $size: '$myArray'
        }
    }
}, {
    $sort: {
        dim: -1
    }
}];
```

The next step (with which I am struggling) would be adding a **position** attribute to each projected document, showing its position in the returned collection. The result would look like:

```
{ "name" : "Adam", dim : 3, position: 1}
{ "name" : "Bill", dim: 2, position: 2}
{ "name" : "Joe", dim: 1, position: 3}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query

- `$setWindowFields` can do it, requires >= MongoDB 5
- here `$rank` is used and each document will have diffrent rank even if same array size, in case you want the same array size to have the same rank also you can use `$denseRank` instead of `$rank`

[Playmongo](https://cmql.org/playmongo/?q=628130d2853f039c69b0f8db)

```js
aggregate(
[{"$set": {"size": {"$size": "$myArray"}}},
 {"$setWindowFields": 
   {"sortBy": {"size": -1},
    "output": {"position": {"$rank": {}}}}}])
```